# Inconsistency of button positions in review queues

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, review-audits, design

The buttons of 4 of the review queues can be characterized as positive, somewhat positive, negative and neutral (skip). The problem is that the order of the buttons is not consistent across the review queues:

> [image: Review queue buttons characterized]

<sup>Please don't downvote, because there is no hand drawn circle or arrow.</sup>

### small Proposition

At least exchange the `Edit` and the `Recommend Deletion` buttons in the low quality review queue. This would mean the least problems with the community.

Changing the order of the reopen votes review queue buttons might be strange since there could be different reasons behind the ordering.

### big Proposition

It would be probably best if all the buttons would be ordered like: positive, somewhat positive, negative and *skip*. This would mean that Suggested Edits, Close Votes and Reopen Votes need to be reordered. If reviewers who are not looking anymore where they click but know what they what to achieve, this will lead to some wrong clicks during the time of adaption but more correct clicks in the long run.

### Why is this my problem?

I have failed some audits in the suggested edits and low quality posts review queues because of the inconsistencies. Since the suggested edits queue is a "high speed" queue, I begin to move the mouse to the right position before I have finally decided. If I reviewed some posts in the low quality queue before that, I am in a different mindset which means I will move the mouse to the wrong position when I want to reject an edit. The same happens in the other direction.

Currently, this is only a problem with review audits because an audit doesn't let me notice my error, but I will immediately fail the audit. This is not a problem with real reviews since edit/improve and delete/reject need a second action. It would be better if I didn't even had to notice my error.

### Why is this a problem?

Review queues are not "full". You have to jump between the queues frequently. Every time you go to another queue, you need to keep in mind that the action layout has changed. This introduces unnecessary stress to the reviewer.

Comment: `Since the suggested edits queue is a "high speed" queue`  No, it should not be.  No one should just be hammering right through edits without taking a careful look at them.

Comment: I wonder if continuously changing the position would slow down robo-reviewers, or even annoy them enough to quit...

Comment: @jonsca It kinda is, since the edit must be reviewed in a timely manner, because it locks other editors out for that time. It doesn't mean that I am sluggish because of that, just that I am aware that I don't have the time to open the question in question and investigate if the edit is really warranted (were a comment is moved into the question by another person). This is only an example why *I* move the cursor before I finally decide. It is only limited to this queue.

Comment: `I have failed some audits in the suggested edits and low quality posts review queues because of the inconsistencies`  I'm not sure you should worry about other editors if that's the case.  Take your time, and don't make it so mechanical that you are making mistakes any more than once in a blue moon.  I think you are imposing constraints on yourself that aren't really there.

Comment: Incidentally, the handful of your reviews that I looked at seemed to be fairly solid, so that's really the most important thing.  Quality over quantity is more than just an adage.  If you're trying to review quickly to keep things out of the hands of poor reviewers, this proposal will only help their cause rather than thwart them as @Arjan has pointed out above.

Comment: I disagree with your Reopen Votes queue alignment. I would definitely expect the Leave Closed button to be at the left to match the Leave Open and Looks Ok buttons. It's the "there really isn't anything to do with this post" button.

Comment: @animuson You have another view on what you want to convey with the button order. My understanding is that `Reopen` is undoubtedly positive, so `Leave Closed` must be negative. I see that the Reopen Votes queue can be seen differently than the other 3. That is why I have 2 propositions.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing all the edit buttons including the edit and reopen button and improve button all as the second to last button; so right next to skip; second to last.

Comment: @ArtjomB. just so you and anyone else looking knows. Changes have been made to the suggested edits queue, so when you are reviewing an edit , it locks out other people from reviewing it or something, so it's not a *high speed* queue anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why the buttons should be organized according to how you feel about the post. It makes more sense to me that they're organized according to how you feel about it in being in that queue: from "Yes, this should be closed/reopened/deleted/approved" to "No, this was wrongly put in the queue and should be left closed/not closed/not deleted/rejected" with Edit/Improve etc in between.

However, I **more strongly feel** that they shouldn't be in any kind of expected order at all, not even the same order all the time for the same queue. You should slow down and read the post, read the buttons, and **think about what you're doing**, not mash through as quickly as you can. This applies even in the queues where robo reviewers will process 4 posts while you do a single one. The robo reviewer problem is not as bad as it once was, so it is being tackled other ways. Trying to make good reviewers into roboly-good button mashers is no solution.

Comment: I feel like the only thing that is taken from my post is that I want to smash through the reviews as fast as possible. No, that is not what I am talking about. A human makes some observations like there most review queues have 4 buttons. On using those buttons a categorization emerges which does not work for every queue. As an experienced reviewer I shouldn't be artificially slowed down. When I review, I know what I want to do and then I have to artificially figure out where that option is that I want to click. It just causes stress without any benefit.

Comment: I really don't think that randomizing the order is such a good idea. This would make reviewing too inconvenient that the reviewer would quit reviewing. That's how I feel at least. The last point: robo-reviewers probably don't care about order.

Comment: If you start randomising the button order, not only you will inconvenience the reviewers, you will also help robots hide better because their approve ratios will approach 50% rather than 95%.